# vue.js insert block for every 6th loop element

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, vue-component

I have offers cards list rendering thru the loop. Every 3rd col (bootstrap) elements i add row div. Now i need to add another col element (banner block) for every 6th element. For render some thing like that:

[image]

How i can implement that?

My code now

```
<div class="row" v-for="i in Math.ceil(offers.length / 3)">
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12" v-for="offer in offers.slice((i-1)*3, i*3)">
        <h2>{{offer.name}}</h2>
        <h2>{{offer.desc}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you do less programming in the view and more in the view model. Create a `computed` that splits up your data into series of offers and banners, and also into rows, then use that computed in a straightforward way.

```js
const chunk = (arr, size) =>
  arr
  .reduce((acc, _, i) =>
    (i % size) ?
    acc :
    [...acc, arr.slice(i, i + size)], []);
    
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    offers: []
  },
  computed: {
    rows() {
      const withBanners = chunk(this.offers, 5).map((arr) => [...arr, {name: 'banner', type: 'Banner'}]).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);

      return chunk(withBanners, 3);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.offers = [{
        name: 'offer'
      },
      {
        name: 'offer'
      },
      {
        name: 'offer'
      },
      {
        name: 'offer'
      },
      {
        name: 'offer'
      },
      {
        name: 'offer'
      },
      {
        name: 'offer'
      },
      {
        name: 'offer'
      },
      {
        name: 'offer'
      },
      {
        name: 'offer'
      },
      {
        name: 'offer'
      }
    ];
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  display: grid;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  justify-content: left;
}

.box {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
}

.banner {
  background-color: #f9c;
}

.offer {
  background-color: #99f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="row" v-for="row in rows">
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12" v-for="item in row">
      <div v-if="item.type === 'Banner'" class="banner box">
        <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
      </div>
      <div v-else class="offer box">
        <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But i'm getting offers from server via axios

Comment: It doesn't matter where you get it from. The computed will be correct when offers gets assigned.

Comment: I have updated the snippet to assign offers after the program has started.

Comment: And one more problem, banner does not replace (in query) 6th offer and this offer drop down in new row and i got 7 cols, not 6. Plus banner append to the end, no matter how much offers in list

Comment: These are all things you can handle in the computed. Make it generate the data you want to work with.

Answer (score 8):

for loop:

```
    <div class="mycol" v-for="(offer,ind) in offers">
      <template v-if="ind % 5 == 0">
       <h2>banner</banner>
      </template>
      <template v-else>
       <h2>{{offer.name}}</h2>
       <h2>{{offer.desc}}</h2>
      </template>
    </div>
```

for new line for every third col you can use css

```
.mycol:nth-child(3n+1){
 clear:left;
}
```

Comment: this is quite easy and simple,

Answer (score 4):

This should do exactly what you want.. I had to manipulate the data some because Vue's templating language is not designed to handle the logic for this kind of use case

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="items in rows" class="row">
    <div v-for="item in items" class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
created () {
    while (this.items.length > 0) {
      const howMany = (this.rows.length % 3 === 0) ? 3 : 2
      const row = this.items.splice(0, howMany)
      if (howMany === 2) row.push('banner')
      this.rows.push(row)

    }
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jamesharrington/k6c0rgL3/17/

Comment: If he does this, the 6th will disappear,

Comment: But what about row div driving for each 3d rows?

Comment: Im sorry, but the 6th element will be replaced by banner. Is this what he wants?

Comment: @RaphaelParreira I changed it so that wouldn't happen but I'm trying to figure out the 3 per row issue

Comment: Ok i think i got it :)

Comment: Does not work. I think because i receiving my offers from server by axios (in method)

Comment: Ah ok well you can just put that created while loop in the response from your server

Comment: Perfect but one last moment banner does not have offers params (like name, description, url etc) which i call in html {{offer.name}}...

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to add a banner every 6 elemtns, but you want to show the 6th. I would handle this on my data object, inserting the banner inside it. It is easier. You could split your array on this way.

```
let firstPart = myData.slice(0,5)
let lastPart = myData.slice(5,)

let newData = [...firstPart, banner, ...lastPart]
```

Now, you just need to do this every 6 elements.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use flex if it is possible.
So the code will look like: http://jsfiddle.net/n89dbo37/

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        items: _.times(20, i => ({type: 'offer'})),
    };
  },
  computed: {
    itemsWithBanners() {
      let result = [];
      this.items.forEach((item, idx) => {
        if (idx && idx % 5 === 0) {
            result.push({type: 'banner'});
        }
        result.push(item);
      });
      return result;
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone, i took Roy J solution, rebuild for my case and get result. My code:

```
<template>
  <div class="section-space80 results-col" >
    <div class="container" >
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="wrapper-content bg-white pinside40">
              <div class="row" v-for="row in rows">
                <div v-for="offer in row" class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                  <div class="lender-listing" v-if="offer.type && offer.type === 'Banner'">
                    <div class="lender-head">
                        Banner
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="lender-listing" v-if="offer.mfoName">
                    <div class="lender-head">
                        <div class="lender-logo">Offer</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  const chunk = (arr, size) =>
  arr
  .reduce((acc, _, i) =>
    (i % size) ?
    acc :
    [...acc, arr.slice(i, i + size)], []);

  import axios from 'axios'
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        showOffers: true,
        loanOffers: [],
        isVisible: false,
        loadMore: true,
        offset: 0,
        rows: ''

      }
    },

    methods: {
      getOffersList: function () {
        let dataElements = this
        dataElements.loading = true
        axios.get('/api/v1/getUserOffers')
          .then(function (response) {
            dataElements.loanOffers = response.data
            const withBanners = chunk(dataElements.loanOffers, 5).map((arr) => [...arr, {name: 'banner', type: 'Banner'}]).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));
            dataElements.rows = chunk(withBanners, 3);
          })
      },
    },
    beforeMount(){
      this.getOffersList()
    }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I offer to use template and loop over it.
Then inside you check v-if="i%6" --> your article v-else --> yuor ad.